# FireSharp QueryBuilder return null

Tags: c#, .net, query-builder, fire-sharp

i hope this question afford all the standards.Im trying to do a notification service using Firebease with the firesharp library.Im able to connect my app and insert data into my firebase, and, if i ask for an specific object, im able to retrieve the content,but is not what i need.The idea is being checking every last insert into the firebase and acordding to this notify the clients...the problem begin when i try to use QueryBuilder like this :

```
    public static void SelectAsync(string Query,Data Target)
    {

        FirebaseResponse response = client.Get(FireSharp.QueryBuilder.New("Information").OrderBy("ID").LimitToLast(1).ToQueryString());

        Data T = new Data();
        T=response.ResultAs<Data>();
        Console.WriteLine(T.ID.ToString());



    }
```

T ever return null

--The rules of my firebase

> {
>     "rules": {
>       ".read": true,
>       ".write": true,
>        "Information":{
>          ".indexOn":["ID"]
>        }
>     }
>   }

I dont know where the problem is,i hope somebody can help me

ps: Calling the method

```
        private  async void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        FireBase Fire = new FireBase();
        Fire.Config();
        var data = new Data();
        await Task.Run(()=>FireBase.SelectAsync("Information",data));

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use GetAsync, it works for me.

```
private async Task button_RetrieveRangeData_Click()
{               
    FirebaseResponse resp1 = await client.GetAsync("Information", FireSharp.QueryBuilder.New().OrderBy ("ID").LimitToLast(1));
}
```